# Prove that an infinite decimal whose digits are natural numbers strung end to end is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

The question is from the book The Foundation of Mathematics by Ian Stewart.

Let
$y = 0·1234567891011121314151617181920 . . . $,

whose digits are the natural numbers in decimal form, strung end to
end. Prove that y is irrational.

This is how I solved it.

I assumed the number is of the form $a_0.a_1a_2a_3.......$
where $a_n = a + nd$ and $a = 0, d = 1$

So if there is no repetition in the infinite decimal places then the number is irrational.

All I had to prove was that assume to there is a repetition after $a_n$ from $a_{n+1}$ till $a_{n+k}$ and if $a_{n+1} \ne a_{n+k+1}$ then there is no repetition and the series must be irrational.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: A more general problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97878/what-type-of-number-is-x

Answer (score 1):

This is [Champernowne's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant). It is not just irrational, it
is transcendental. An easy way to prove that it is irrational is
that the number has arbitrarily long strings of $1$s and
arbitrarily long strings of $2$s. So given any putative
period length, it has infinitely many strings of $1$s and of $2$s
of that length. Transcendence is harder....

Comment: Could you explain it in an elaborate way, I am sorry, I am totally lost.